# Using variables and variables scope in AJAX and Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, variables, scope

I have trouble with using variables in AJAX. I want var x to remember data from var data. However when I check in the console log the value is undefined. Can somebody help me with this? EDIT: I need to use the variable x later in the code. It's not just about checking the value.

```
var x;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var results = new Array();
            var numberOfSuggestions = 0;

            var data = xmlhttp.responseText;                
            var data = eval(data);
            x = data;

            /*
            some code
            */
        }
    }
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are outputting variable x outside the callback function of the `xmlhttp.onreadystatechange` event, which will only be called, when the event triggers.

In order to see the value assigned to x after the Request completed, put your console.log into the callback function.

```
var x;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
            var results = new Array();
            var numberOfSuggestions = 0;

            var data = xmlhttp.responseText;                
            var data = eval(data);
            x = data;
            console.log(x);
            /*
            some code
            */
        }
    }
```

Comment: Ok, but i want to use the variable x later on. It's not about seeing the x value. It's about saving the value for later.

Comment: Either use a synchronous ajax call - using jQuery for example - or use the callback to trigger the next function needed.

I think you need to seriously learn about async programming.

Something like this: http://recurial.com/programming/understanding-callback-functions-in-javascript/

Answer (score 0):

As AJAX is asynchronous, your `console.log(x)` is executed before the response is ready to be evaluated. You have to write the `var x` dependent code synchronously. You can put the code that uses `var x` in a function and then call that function after the response is ready and can be evaluated.

```
var x;

var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200) {
        var results = new Array();
        var numberOfSuggestions = 0;

        var data = xmlhttp.responseText;                
        var data = eval(data);
        x = data;

        /*
        var x dependent code 
              OR
        xdependentFunc(x);
        */
    }
}

function xdependentFunc(x){
  /*
   use x...............
  */
}
console.log(x);
```